# How to add decimals to switch?

Tags: switch-statement, double, decimal, calculator, static-cast

I've been assigned a homework and I seem to have worked most of its coding. The only problem I'm facing is that the professor used what seems to be variables `double` for `x` and `y` when I'm sure we can only use `int, long,` and `char` when using `switch` (We are restricted to use switch and not if/else loop).
I think I am supposed to use `setprecision(3)` or `static_cast(double)< >` since we studied those, but I am not sure how to add them in the code.

This is the output required:

```
Welcome to my Calculator!

1. Addition
2. Multiplication
3. Division
4. Subtraction
5. Modula
Enter operation number, or -1 to quit: 1

Enter first number: 3.899999
Enter second number: 4.000001

3.900 + 4.000 = 7.900

1. Addition
2. Multiplication
3. Division
4. Subtraction
5. Modula
Enter operation number, or -1 to quit: 2

Enter first number: 2.34
Enter second number: 76.44422

2.340 * 76.444 = 178.879

1. Addition
2. Multiplication
3. Division
4. Subtraction
5. Modula
Enter operation number, or -1 to quit: 3

Enter first number: 2.342
Enter second number: 1.321

2.342 / 1.321 = 1.773

1. Addition
2. Multiplication
3. Division
4. Subtraction
5. Modula
Enter operation number, or -1 to quit: 4

Enter first number: -3411
Enter second number: 2454

-3411.000 - 2454.000 = -5865.000

1. Addition
2. Multiplication
3. Division
4. Subtraction
5. Modula
Enter operation number, or -1 to quit: 5

Enter first integer: 10
Enter second integer: 3

10 % 3 = 1

1. Addition
2. Multiplication
3. Division
4. Subtraction
5. Modula
Enter operation number, or -1 to quit: 6
Wrong input! Try again!


1. Addition
2. Multiplication
3. Division
4. Subtraction
5. Modula
Enter operation number, or -1 to quit: 56
Wrong input! Try again!


1. Addition
2. Multiplication
3. Division
4. Subtraction
5. Modula
Enter operation number, or -1 to quit: 5

Enter first integer: 6
Enter second integer: 5

6 % 5 = 1

1. Addition
2. Multiplication
3. Division
4. Subtraction
5. Modula
Enter operation number, or -1 to quit: -1
Goodbye!!
```

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    //variable introduction
    int op_num;     //number of the operation
    int x;          // value of first integer
    int y;          // value of second integer

    int sum;        //answer for addition
    int mul;        //answer for multiplication
    int div;        //answer for division
    int sub;        //answer for subtraction
    int mod;        //answer for modula

    //initialization phase
    cout << "Welcome to my Calculator!\n\n";

    cout << "1. Addition\n"
         << "2. Multiplication\n"
         << "3. Division\n"
         << "4. Subtraction\n"
         << "5. Modula\n" << endl;

    cout << "Enter operation number, or -1 to quit: ";
    cin >> op_num;

    //processing phase
    while (op_num != -1)
    {
        cout << "\nEnter first number: ";
        cin >> x;

        cout << "Enter second number: ";
        cin >> y;

        sum = x + y;        //addition equation
        mul = x * y;        //multiplication equation
        div = x / y;        //division equation
        sub = x - y;        //subtraction equation
        mod = x % y;        //modula equation

        switch (op_num)
        {
            case 1: cout << "\n" << x << " + "
                         << y << " = " << sum << endl;
                         break;

            case 2: cout << "\n" << x << " * "
                         << y << " = " << mul << endl;
                         break;

            case 3: cout << "\n" << x << " / "
                         << y << " = " << div << endl;
                         break;

            case 4: cout << "\n" << x << " - "
                         << y << " = " << sub << endl;
                         break;

            case 5: cout << "\n" << x << " % "
                         << y << " = " << mod << endl;
                         break;

            default: cout << "Wrong input! Try again!\n";
                          break;
        }

        cout << "1. Addition\n"
             << "2. Multiplication\n"
             << "3. Division\n"
             << "4. Subtraction\n"
             << "5. Modula\n" << endl;

        cout << "Enter operation number, or -1 to quit: ";
        cin >> op_num;

    }

    cout << "Goodbye!!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If there's anything I missed or a better way to sum up the coding, please do share!

Comment: @rekire you are right. I did try 0 as the second number, and the program crashed. why is that? I also think that requirements are not completely correct, but I wanted to be sure before submitting my work.

Comment: Since it is a homework, I'll just give you hints: You are doing all operations at once which is not necessary and cause your bug.

Answer (score 0):

From your code `op_num` is the variable used for the switch but not `x` or `y`. So it does it matter if the variable `x` and `y` are doubles? The answer is no. Also you included all your equations outside the `switch`. In the requirements, you don't have to calculate `mul = x * y; div = x / y; sub = x - y;mod = x % y;` when the user enters `op_num` as 1. So move these equations to their respective cases in the switch. That would solve all your bugs.